# Liferay 7 Service Builder Error [NoClassDefFoundError]

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-service-builder

I'm working on Liferay and Salesforce. I'm new to Liferay and I'm experiencing an issue that I spent too much time on.

I have a portlet that I decided to create a Service Builder (named "newService"). Here is my service.xml :

```
<service-builder package-path="com.fr.liferay">
    <namespace>SSB</namespace>
    <entity local-service="true" name="Comp" remote-service="false" uuid="true">
    <!--<entity name="Foo" table="foo" uuid="true" local-service="true" remote-service="false" data-source="sampleDataSource" session-factory="sampleSessionFactory" tx-manager="sampleTransactionManager">-->

        <!-- PK fields -->

        <column name="compId" primary="true" type="long" />

        <!-- Group instance -->

        <column name="groupId" type="long" />

        <!-- Audit fields -->

        <column name="companyId" type="long" />
        <column name="userId" type="long" />
        <column name="userName" type="String" />
        <column name="createDate" type="Date" />
        <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />

        <!-- Other fields -->

        <column name="compName" type="String" />
        <column name="compDesc" type="String" />
        <column name="compPath" type="String" />

        <!-- Order -->

        <!-- References -->

    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

Now, I run the maven command :`mvn service-builder:build` and it generated the `newService-api` artifact.

I'm calling the service inside my portlet as follows:

`Comp comp = CompLocalServiceUtil.createComp(3);
 comp.persist();`

I added the `newservice-api` dependency in the portlet's pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fr.liferay.liferay7-
                architecture.portail7.services.newService</groupId>
    <artifactId>newService-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

On launching my portlet, I get this error :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fr/liferay/service/CompLocalServiceUtil
    at com.fr.liferay.controllers.TestController.actionTwoMethod(TestController.java:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:367)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleAction(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:285)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doActionService(DispatcherPortlet.java:666)
    ... 181 more
12:55:57,243 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-5][render_portlet_jsp:131] null
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fr/liferay/service/CompLocalServiceUtil
    at com.fr.liferay.controllers.TestController.actionTwoMethod(TestController.java:151)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:105)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletExceptionAdapter.service(ServletExceptionAdapter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.FilterExceptionAdapter.doFilter(FilterExceptionAdapter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Where do you have your newService-api in the portlet war file?

Comment: Why do you use `Comp comp = CompLocalServiceUtil.createComp(3);` ? Have you implemented your overriden method in `CompImpl`?

Comment: Well the newService-api is actually supposed to be called from the osgi and not the portlet as far as I know,
And about the CompImpl, I actually didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write this as comment but it's too long so I can only post it as answer, sorry.

You create your enitity and all persistense/model/etc stuff is done by ServiceBuilder. In Liferay 7 it is represented by two modules: api and service. After maven's "build" and servicebuilder's "build-service" you can use default crud methods such as `CompLocalServiceUtil.deleteComp()` and others. And you have written that you use `CompLocalServiceUtil.createComp(3)` which means that you've already overriden that default method in `CompLocalServiceImpl.java` file. Is it true? If not - it's exactly why you have your error.

If you want to add your own business logic - you should modified (and build-service again) `CompLocalServiceImpl`, if you want to add you own model - you should modify `CompImpl.java`

May be I just misunderstand you.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer,
Ah I see what you mean. Well I don't modify the crud methods generated by the service builder, as soon as they're generated I just use them without any modification.